# Liferay Tomcat Server gives warning message on server console continuously

Tags: java, tomcat, server, liferay

My project run Liferay Tomcat server, but from few days its give some warning message continuously that fill server console log .

> 00:53:42,902 WARN  [http-bio-80-exec-177][SecurityPortletContainerWrapper:623]  Reject process action for http://www.myurl.com/welcome on 49

What is the meaning of this warning, we did not change any setting.
Please tell me how we solve this issue.

Comment: Could you cross check if you are correctly creating action URL for the given action,as per the specs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is sometimes due to a missing property in your portlet configuration file. Add the following property to your **portlet.xml**:

```
<add-default-resource>true</add-default-resource>
```